# html() not reading urls from list correctly

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to scrape the pdfs from a site. I could download them all manually, but it's a learning exercise so that I can do more sites later.

I am trying to use rvest and I have the basic functionality down.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

trial <- 'http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2015-annual-public-report'
page2<- html(trial)
page2 %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% str_subset(".pdf") %>% download.file("~/downloads/file.pdf")
```

I would like to do this for all the annual reports. So I have tried:

```
url <- 'http://www.fairlabor.org/impact/reports'
page<- html(url)
links_init <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
links <- links_init[seq(from = 53, to = 72, by = 2)]
new_urls <- paste0(url, links)

# trying to repeat the above basic example. If it succeeds, I can put in a for loop.
test <- html(new_urls[2])
test %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% str_subset(".pdf")
```

Instead, I get a null result, because it appears to be scraping a different page. I don't know why this would be the case since `page2` and `test` appear to be the same character string.

Anyone know what is happening here and how I can correct it?

I tried explicitly making my vector of urls `new_urls` into strings with `as.character(quote())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the base URL, it seems there are report for the year 2003 to 2017. We can first created a list of `urls` for those years

```
urls <- paste0("http://www.fairlabor.org/report/",seq(2003, 2017),
               "-annual-public-report")

urls
# [1] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2003-annual-public-report"
# [2] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2004-annual-public-report"
# [3] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2005-annual-public-report"
# [4] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2006-annual-public-report"
# [5] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2007-annual-public-report"
# [6] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2008-annual-public-report"
# [7] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2009-annual-public-report"
# [8] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2010-annual-public-report"
# [9] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2011-annual-public-report"
#[10] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2012-annual-public-report"
#[11] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2013-annual-public-report"
#[12] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2014-annual-public-report"
#[13] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2015-annual-public-report"
#[14] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2016-annual-public-report"
#[15] "http://www.fairlabor.org/report/2017-annual-public-report"
```

Now, report for every URL is not present which might result in an error, so we can use `tryCatch` to skip those reports from downloading. We can use `lapply` to download reports from all the `urls`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

lapply(urls, function(x) tryCatch({ x %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  str_subset(".pdf") %>%
  download.file(paste0("~/downloads/", basename(x), ".pdf"))}, 
  error = function(e) { }))
```

This would download pdf reports in your download folders named `2003-annual-public-report.pdf`, `2006-annual-public-report.pdf` and so on.

Comment: Thank you! This code missed out on 2004 and 2005 reports, so I added a `map` around the `download.file`:
`map(., download.file(., paste0("~/downloads/", basename(x)))}`